# How to include external contentProvider(any api) package into android.jar in android

Tags: android, jar

I want to include contentProvider(say for some application) package in to android.jar.

I was able to include it in sdk, well I could not do include in android.jar.

It would be helpfull for me if i can include those apis in android.jar for my further development in eclipse.And to specify there are no proper documentation available as such.

Kindly provide the steps to include external api into android.jar or any documents.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to include contentProvider(say
>   for some application) package in to
>   android.jar.

`android.jar` is simply a stub library used to allow your Java code to compile with `javac`, despite the fact that most of the APIs are actually embedded in the device. Nothing from `android.jar` gets included in your APK, except perhaps some constants.

*If* you work for a device manufacturer and *if* you wish to make an extended API available to third-party developers, the official way to do that is to create an SDK add-on, similar to the Google Maps add-on. This does not involve modifying `android.jar` AFAIK, but uses a different process with a separate JAR. You might inquire on the [android-porting] Google Group][1](http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting), or via your Open Handset Alliance liaison, for more details about this process.